# How to make a collapsible sidebar with HTML, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the right side of the browser have a collapsible sidebar that expands out from the right for about 400 pixels that contains various div tags and text in it and collapses when the user clicks on the edge of the sidebar. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: The best way is to try first then ask about specific problem.

Comment: googled it to get: http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-collapsible-sidebar-layout/ collapsible sidebar tutorial using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can very easily be done with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Check out the "[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)" and "[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)" methods.